# How can I change the expected file type of MaxFileSize from int to long?

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, devexpress-blazor

[image]

I need to change the expected file type from `int` to `long` so that I can increase the range of maximum file size  (maxfilesize) to at least of 50 GB.

What could be the general approach or how can I change the type shortly?

Comment: You cannot change the type for `MaxFileSize` property of  `DxUpload` class because you don't own it - it's a part of DevExpress components - check this https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1028696/upload-for-blazor-how-to-upload-really-big-files-up-to-20gb-with-dxupload-v21-1